# How to insert image in ContentTool Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using Content tool Plugin which is a brilliant plugin but I'm experiencing some error

When i click on insert image button

this is what php file send me in response

```
{"url":"\/\/cdn.example.com\/blog\/image\/wzClxXEupWKm.jpg","size":[600,400]}
```

but mozilla console is giving error

```
TypeError: image.size is undefined
'data-ce-max-width': image.size[0]
```

little part of plugin where error is triggered

```
if (parseInt(ev.target.status) === 200) {
                // Unpack the response (from JSON)
                var response = JSON.parse(ev.target.responseText);

                // Trigger the save event against the dialog with details of the
                // image to be inserted.
                dialog.save(
                    response.url,
                    response.size,
                    {
                        'alt': response.alt,
                        'data-ce-max-width': image.size[0]
                    });

            } else {
                // The request failed, notify the user
                new ContentTools.FlashUI('no');
            }
```

@ContentTools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code it should be `response.size[0]` not `image.size[0]`.

*(This is a typo from the tutorial so thank you for highlighting, I have made the amendment.)*